# How to NOT UserControl.dispose()

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a situation where the user clicks on the X of the UserControl and if a certain condiition exists, I want to keep displaying the user control. I thought that calling `base.Dispose(false)` would do the trick, but it does not.
How do I do this?

FeatureView.Designer.cs

```
partial class FeatureView
{
    // User clicked the X on the control
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Note: base.GetType() = FeatureView
        if (someCondition) // then dispose
        {
            base.Dispose(true);
        }
        else // keep displaying the Feature, do not dispose
        {
            base.Dispose(false);  // nope
        }
    }
 }
```

FeatureView.cs

```
 public partial class FeatureView : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
 {

 }
```

Comment: You better not put custom code in the .Designer.cs file, use the regular .cs file instead.

Comment: Is the X in the user control itself or the form?

Comment: Most programmers do this by accident, a very common cause of hard-to-diagnose leaks.  Use the parent's Controls.Remove() method and it won't get disposed when you close the form.  Keeping a reference to it so you can add it back to a new form instance and dispose when necessary is however important.  And not that obvious to implement, probably needs a static variable.

Comment: Show the code you run when the user presses this "X" feature you have.

Comment: @LarsTech: The `Dispose()` method above is called.

Comment: A UserControl does not have an X.  So how does yours have one?

Comment: As @FlorianRoudaut suggests, it must be embedded in a form. I am currently trying to figure this is out. Ancient, arcane code.

Comment: @ikkentim The `Dispose` method is the one exception to this rule.  Any customization in this method *must* be made in the designer file, and the designer knows not to overwrite it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your user control must be embedded in a form to be visible. At the form lvel you can catch the FormClosing event and set cancel to true.

```
this.FormClosing += Form_ManageFavorites_FormClosing;

private void Form_ManageFavorites_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Something is not right, not sure what. `this.FormClosing()` does not exist. `this.FindForm()` returns null.